# error: cannot catch reference to incomplete type

Tags: c++

вот имеется подобный хедер:

```
class A
{
    public:
        ...
        class MyException1;
        class MyException2;
        ...
    private:
        int a;
        void check_condition() const;
};

class MyException2: public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const throw();
};

class MyException1: public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const throw();
};
```

суть в том, что есть два класса, которые вложены в основной. эти классы наследуются от класса исключений.

в классе А имеется функция check_condition, которая, проверяя условия, бросает один из MyException. и если по логике кажется правильным, по факту этот код не компилируется и бросает ошибку.
указывая на строчку из cpp с блоками catch. если ловлю просто ссылку на std::exception, то все нормально компилируется и работает, но в таком случае надо повторно проверять условия для соответствия одному из исключений, а если подставить MyException - уже ругается. оч хочется разделить обработку ошибок без внутренних проверок условия, но не понимаю как.

хочу, чтоб работало примерно так:

```
try { check_condition(); }
catch(A::MyExcetion1& e) {...;}
catch(A::MyException2& e) {...;}
```

функция check_condition() имеет условно следующую реализацию:

```
void A::check_condition()
{
    if (this->a < 1)
        throw A::MyException1();
    if (this->a > 1000)
        throw A::MyExceprion2();
}
```

функция `check_condition()` используется в конструкторе класса `А(int a)` и в функциях типа `setA(int a)` `incrementA()` `decrementA()`.

Comment: Покажите полный код. Пока что вызывает подозрение, что вы не используете полностью квалифицированные имена типа `A::MyException1`.

Comment: я пробовал подставлять и полностью квалифицированные имена, и не полностью... по факту `check_condition()` используется только внутри класса А, как и блоки try/catch, поэтому эта функция является приватной. но тип ошибки не менялся. бросать тоже пытался и с полным именем, и без.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A
{
    int a{};
public:
    //...
    class MyException1;
    class MyException2;
   // ...
    void check_condition() const;
      
};
class A::MyException2 : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const throw() 
    { return "error2"; }
};
class A::MyException1 : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const throw() 
    { return "error1"; }
};
void A::check_condition() const
{
    if (a < 1)
        throw MyException1();
    if (a > 1000)
        throw MyException2();
}
int main()
{   
    A a;
    try { a.check_condition(); }
    catch (A::MyException1 & e) 
    { e.what(); /*...*/ }
    catch (A::MyException2 & e) 
    { e.what(); /*...*/ }    
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что вы определяете классы, никак не связанные с классом `А` (`class A::MyException1` и `class MyException1` совершенно разные классы). И чтобы функция член могла создать экземпляры класса, ее определение должно быть позже определения этих классов. Чтобы что то создать, сначала нужно знать что из себя оно представляет.

Comment: спасибо, я действительно долго не мог заметить подобного недочета своего кода.

Comment: пожалуйста, но знайте, что это покатит только как учебная тренировка. В принципе подход плохой. Если  Base& может ссылаться и на D! и на D2, то лучше   передать Base&, а не заводить более одной функции(в данном случаи обработчика). А еще лучше  держать только один класс исключений, а в самом классе реализовывать желаемое количество методов

Comment: как вы точно угадали, это и есть моя учебная тренировка. ваши доводы звучат действительно логично, что даже немного отбивает желания реализовывать все подобным образом. жаль что в вопросе структуры у меня на самом деле мало свободы в данном случае. ведь иначе будет fail. надеюсь у меня получится запомнить данное замечание и на практике постараюсь придерживаться этого совета.

Comment: Ну вот, а мне вы ответили, что *я пробовал подставлять и полностью квалифицированные имена, и не полностью* :) Значит, не пробовали.

Comment: да, я изначально подумал что не в хедере, а в спп файле.. там я правда пробовал полностью. сознаюсь, мой косяк, я не правильно понял вас :(